# How to restart a script if a string is equal to Y or y?

Tags: c#, loops, do-while

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        {
            string value;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("First value to add? : ");
                int a1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Second value to add? : ");
                int a2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write(a1+a2);
                Console.WriteLine("Type Y or y to restart the program.");
                value = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            while (value == "Y" || "y");
        } 
    }
}
```

I get this error:

source.cs(1,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected. I think that the script cant access the string but idk.

I expected that the script would restart

Comment: `while (value == "Y" || value == "y")`

Comment: Or using pattern matching: `while (value is "Y" or "y")`

Comment: I get the same error code,/using System;
     
public class Program
{
 public static void Main()
 {
  {
   string value;
   do
   {
    Console.WriteLine("First value to add? : ");
    int a1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Second value to add? : ");
    int a2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write(a1+a2);
    Console.WriteLine("Type Y or y to restart the program.");
    restart = Console.ReadLine();
   }
   while (value == "Y" || value == "y");
  } 
 }
}

Comment: Other than the error pointed out by Jonathan, the code you show above will not produce the error you say it does. So that error must be coming from somewhere else. Is this Unity perhaps? Do you have a csproj file?

Comment: im using an online c# compiler, maybe its outdated, im at school so i cant use visual studio

Comment: I suspect the problem is in there then. Try a different one. For example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q9ODVl

Comment: I'd actually use `ReadKey` for that.